# Understanding the ORA_ROWSCN behavior in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

So this is essentially a follow-up question on [Finding duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319473/oracle-deleting-duplicates-from-table-with-auto-generated-key-as-primary-key).

We perform data imports from text files everyday and we ended up importing 10163 records spread across 182 files twice. On running the query mentioned above to find duplicates, the total count of records we got is 10174, which is 11 records more than what are contained in the files. I assumed about the posibility of 2 records that are  exactly the same and are valid ones being accounted for as well in the query. So I thought it would be best to use a timestamp field and simply find all the records that ran today (and hence ended up adding duplicate rows). I used ORA_ROWSCN using the following query:

```
select count(*) from my_table
where TRUNC(SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)) = '01-MAR-2012'
;
```

However, the count is still more i.e. 10168. Now, I am pretty sure that the total lines in the file is 10163 by running the following command in the folder that contains all the files. `wc -l *.txt`.

Is it possible to find out which rows are actually inserted twice?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, `ORA_ROWSCN` is stored at the block level, not at the row level.  It is only stored at the row level if the table was originally built with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` enabled.  Assuming that you can fit many rows of your table in a single block and that you're not using the `APPEND` hint to insert the new data above the existing high water mark of the table, you are likely inserting new data into blocks that already have some existing data in them.  By default, that is going to change the `ORA_ROWSCN` of every row in the block causing your query to count more rows than were actually inserted.

Since `ORA_ROWSCN` is only guaranteed to be an upper-bound on the last time there was DML on a row, it would be much more common to determine how many rows were inserted today by adding a `CREATE_DATE` column to the table that defaults to `SYSDATE` or to rely on `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after your `INSERT` ran (assuming, of course, that you are using a single `INSERT` statement to insert all the rows).

Generally, using the `ORA_ROWSCN` and the `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` function is going to be a problematic way to identify when a row was inserted even if the table is built with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`.  `ORA_ROWSCN` returns an Oracle SCN which is a System Change Number.  This is a unique identifier for a particular change (i.e. a transaction).  As such, there is no direct link between a SCN and a time-- my database might be generating SCN's a million times more quickly than yours and my SCN 1 may be years different from your SCN 1.  The Oracle background process `SMON` maintains a table that maps SCN values to approximate timestamps but it only maintains that data for a limited period of time-- otherwise, your database would end up with a multi-billion row table that was just storing SCN to timestamp mappings.  If the row was inserted more than, say, a week ago (and the exact limit depends on the database and database version), `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` won't be able to convert the SCN to a timestamp and will return an error.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Can you please tell me if I can export data to a delimited file for the query that contains `ORA_ROWSCN`? I am trying to export the data in SQL Developer and the export fails with unrecognized column `ORA_ROWSCN`

Comment: @darkie15 - You should be able to-- I did so just now.  I'm not sure why you'd want to, though-- what benefit would you derive from having the SCN in a flat file?

Comment: I did not mean adding SCN in the file, but when I right clicked on the data tab for my table, clicked export and in the where clause entered ORA_ROWSCN, it threw an error saying OR_ROWSCN is invalid. Anyways I figured it out.

Comment: So, if I want to add ROWDEPENDENCIES now to an existing table, I cannot do an `alter table` if I am right. Can I just drop and recreate the table adding the `ROWDEPENDENCIES`? This link: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1111022 suggests to take out the schema from the service ... Can we not just recreate without touching the schema and adding `ROWDEPENDENCIES`?

Comment: @darkie15 - You can just drop and re-create the table with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` (though you may want to do something to save the data).  But if you're going to do that, you're likely much better served by adding a `CREATE_DATE` column that just defaults to `SYSDATE` rather than relying on the SCN to determine how many rows have been inserted today.

Comment: Makes sense .. I will do just that. I read somewhere(mostly in the oracle documentation) that `ORA_ROWSCN` takes space lesser than an `timestamp` and more than a `number`. And I only see this data (`ORA_ROWSCN` or `CREATE_DATE` you suggest) as a need to provide rollback in case something goes wrong. So I was a bit inclined on `ORA_ROWSCN`

Comment: @darkie15 - Unless you're dealing with billions of rows, the difference in space utilization shouldn't drive design decisions.  A `DATE` is going to be much easier to work with, it is going to work consistently (`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` only works for a few days), it is going to make sense to your users, etc.  That ought to outweigh any potential space savings-- a few MB of disk space is dirt cheap.

Comment: Perfect, I will do just that. However, what do you mean by "`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` only works for a few days"? Isn't that a function that simply converts `ora_rowscn` to timestamp?

Comment: @darkie15 - `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` converts a SCN to a timestamp but it relies on a mapping table maintained by `SMON` and that mapping table is only going to store the most recent few days of data.  If you have data inserted more than, say, a week ago (the exact limit varies with the database and database version), `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn)` will return an error rather than a timestamp.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it is something like Unix timestamp which you can always convert back. So, the table `SMON` contains the mapping of the `ora_rowscn` values against actual timestamp? And if this mapping table deletes a `ora_rowscn` value, the corresponding timestamp is lost? Am I correct in my understanding

Comment: @darkie15 - `SMON` is a background process.  It maintains a table that provides approximate mappings from the SCN to the timestamp.  That mapping table maintains the data for a limited period of time.  The `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` function attempts to use that mapping data to produce an approximate timestamp but if the mapping information is gone, it will throw an error.  `ORA_ROWSCN` is the Oracle `SCN` or System Change Number.  How quickly that number changes depends on how many transactions your database is doing not on elapsed time.  So you wouldn't want Oracle maintaining billions of mappings.