# SQL - When was my table last change?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find  when the last INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement was performed on a table (for now, in the future I want to do this in multiple tables) in an Oracle database.
I created a table and then I updated one of its rows. Now I've the following query:

```
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn) from test_table;
```

This query returns the timestamps of each row, and for each of them it gives the time when they were first created.

But the row that I've updated have the same timestamp as the others. Why? Shouldn't the timestamp be updated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520995/understanding-the-ora-rowscn-behavior-in-oracle has some explanation of why ORA_ROWSCN is not giving the results you expect

Answer (score 0):

ORA_ROWSCN is not the right solution for this.  It is not necessarily reliable at the row level.  Moreover, it's not going to be useful at all for deleted rows.

If you have a real need to know when DML changes were made to a table, you should look at Oracle's auditing feature.

An alternative is to use triggers to record when changes are made to the table.  Since you say you only care about the time of the most recent change, you can just create a single-column table to record the time, and write a trigger that fires on any DML statement to maintain it.  If you're doing this in a production environment or even just in one where more than one session might be modifying the table, you'd want to think about how it should work when concurrent changes are made.  You could force the table to have at most one row, but that would serialize every change to the table.  You could allow each session to insert a separate row and take the max value when querying it, but then you probably want to think about clearing out old rows from time to time.

Comment: I dont need a result at a row level, I mean I just need to know if a table was modified. I dont't have also admin privileges. Doesn't auditing requires admin privileges?

Comment: I don't know specifics off-hand, but I'll say that auditing probably requires more than the most basic privileges.  I guess I'm approaching this from the point of view of working in a production system, where if I had a requirement to record changes, the appropriate action would be to get the DBA involved to set up auditing.  I updated my answer with thoughts on an approach you could implement yourself.