# How know table data increment

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some tables in oracle, but these tables have no date field.
Can I know increment of table data a day by using sql syntax?

thanks

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: Give sample data and expected result

Comment: Without having a date column, I don't think there is any way to get the increment of table data a day.

Comment: This is something that you must think ahead.

Comment: Where is the database hosted?

Comment: Under very limited circumstances you can infer this from SCNs. See the accepted answer here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520995/understanding-the-ora-rowscn-behavior-in-oracle

Comment: Please, describe what do you want to achieve.

Comment: yes, I must think ahead

Answer (score 0):

If you have flashback enabled then, to get the difference between midnight today and midnight yesterday, you can use:

```sql
SELECT primary_key_column
FROM   table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP)
MINUS
SELECT primary_key_column
FROM   table_name AS OF TIMESTAMP TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```